# How to get height value of every textarea?

Tags: angular

I have this method:

```
autogrow(){

 var tareas=document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')

    for(let i = 0; i< tareas.length; i++){
        tareas[i].style.height = (tareas[i].scrollHeight - 10)+"px";
    }

}
```

Some of them have two line of text some of them have one . I want to get value of those heigts for all textarea and change size of them . Any suggestion how can i do that? In my case right now it get same height for all textarea.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by get string length in pixel with a specific font size and compare this length with textarea width as

```
function getWidthOfText(txt, fontname, fontsize){
  // Create a dummy canvas (render invisible with css)
  var c=document.createElement('canvas');
  // Get the context of the dummy canvas
  var ctx=c.getContext('2d');
  // Set the context.font to the font that you are using
  ctx.font = fontsize + fontname;
  // Measure the string 
  // !!! <CRUCIAL>  !!!
  var length = ctx.measureText(txt).width;
  // !!! </CRUCIAL> !!!
  // Return width
  return length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the following assumptions in this solution:

- You are using the "rows" attribute to set the number of rows in each
  text area
- You are using the same font in each text area
- You want the text areas to all be the same size as the text area with the maximum number of rows.
- You have stored your text areas as an array somewhere

Assuming all this is true, I have provided this JavaScript solution:

```
function adjustAllTextAreas() {
    // Replace the following line with your text area storage
    var textAreas = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("example"));
  var maxRows = 0;


    textAreas.forEach(function(item, index){
    if (item.rows > maxRows) {
        maxRows = item.rows;
    }  
  })

  textAreas.forEach(function(item, index){
    item.rows = maxRows;
  })

}
```

Comment: i dont want that all get same size...i want that every have height based by content, but to have on start by default row = 1;

Comment: That's important information that was missing in your original post.

Then what you would want is: 

    function adjustAllTextAreas() {
        // Replace the following line with your text area storage
        var textAreas = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("example"));
  textAreas.forEach(function(item, index){
    textAreas[index].rows = 1;
  })

}

...at least that is what I think that you are requesting?

Comment: Or is what you are asking is that you want all textareas to start at (row, col)  == (1, 1) when the page is rendered?